# why contract is saving the ether in contract rather than sending it directly to senders wallet

Tags: contract-development, remix, payable, callcode

Why the below code is saving the ether to the contract address rather than just directly sending it to sender ?
In remix**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

contract payablee {

    address public sender; 
    address payable public _owner;

    constructor(address _sender) {
        _owner = payable(msg.sender);
        sender= _sender;
    }

    function payToOwner(uint _amount) public payable {
        _owner.transfer(_amount);
    }

    function payToSender(uint _amount) public payable returns(bool) {
        payable(sender).transfer(_amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(uint _amount) public payable {
        (bool success, ) = sender.call{value: _amount}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding more information. We can't help much without knowing which function you're calling, how you're calling it, with what parameters, etc.

Comment: @natewelch_  all 3 functios are actually when executed are storing the send ether (which is _amount param in all 3 function) is storing the ether in the contract itself . It should be directly initated to the recipient wallet address which is actually only 2 right here 1.) _owner and 2.) sender variable . so In remix there is a "Balance: 19.99999 ETH"  in deployed contracts. 
I though the balance will be deducted from the sender address and will be transfered to the recipient address . or I have to use msg.sender ?

Comment: @natewelch_nvm , I figured it out , that I was just sending it the ether to contract itself and amount is to transfer the ether from contract to address to
and if I have to send ether from 1 address to another I have to use msg.sender lmao , 
How can I missed this small dumb mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out .
I have to use msg.value not _amount
_amount is used as a param when contract is sending to a certain address